# python crash course: ch 9- creating a class_ dog example

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance

Hi I'm having trouble figuring out what i'm doing wrong for the following code to produce the error message, i've copied and pasted the same code from the web and it works just fine but when i type it out the defined class does not seem to take arguments.

Input:

```
class Dog():
  """A simple attempt to model a dog"""
  def _init_(self, name, age):
    """initialize name and age attributes."""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def sit(self):
    """simulate dog sitting in response to a command"""
    print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

  def roll_over(self):
    """simulate rolling over in response to a command"""
    print(self.name.title() + " rolled over!")

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sstie/Desktop/python_work/ch.9_retry.py", line 16, in <module>
    my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
TypeError: Dog() takes no arguments
```

Comment: `_init_` needs two more underscores.

Comment: and your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need two underscores in your constructor name:

```
class Dog:
    """A simple attempt to model a dog"""
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        """initialize name and age attributes."""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        """simulate dog sitting in response to a command"""
        print(self.name.title() + " is now sitting.")

    def roll_over(self):
        """simulate rolling over in response to a command"""
        print(self.name.title() + " rolled over!")

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Many [special names](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) in python begin and end with double underscores.